# Old Cron still running - Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04

I have 5 cron jobs running. It has been running correctly all this time

From the past 2 days, the one scheduled at 11 in the night got fired twice.

I changed the time to 10:30PM and checked. The job ran at 10:30PM but also at 11 PM

I edited the cron using crontab -e. I have checked in all cron folders and I don't see this cron

From where is this running and why is there this sudden change in behavior?

It is resulting in duplication of entries in prod database. So any immediate help on this will be very helpful

Thanks in advance
Rathi

Answer (score 0):

In the /etc directory, there are multiple instances of cron. Such as weekly, daily, hourly, and there's even another directory /etc/cron.d most of the time. It is very possible that it is also listed in one of the files located within one of the directories listed.